# Android Activity Closing Flash

Tags: android, android-activity

My issue is simple really, I just don't know how to fix it. I have my app switching between activities, and when it switches to another one, it flashes the last screen from the activity that was just closed when the new activity is finally loaded. I don't really know why this is happening, or I might have an idea of how to approach it, but I do not. Does anyone else have any idea why this happens or how to fix it?

I close the activity in the onPause() of each activity, just calling finish.

Thanks in advance! If you need anything else I will update this with that info.

William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any particular reason to want to finish the activity when onPause() is called? If not, then you should let Android system manage your Activity life cycle.

Comment: For some reason when I don't kill the activity, I get out of memory exceptions, if I try to make another activity with the same class, will it create a whole new one or launch the old one?

Comment: This should not happen under normal circumstances, Android is designed to transiently kill/restart Activities as needed. You should check to see if you have memory leak or inadvertently hold onto something big memory-wise. Also check out this Google IO video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk